# Delete range from Text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a keypad using python tk library. I am running Python version 3.6.3.

1) I have a `Text` widget in my UI. When I press the backspace button, I want to delete the last character in the `Text` widget. I am keeping the count of the total number of characters in the `Text` widget as well.

So far I have tried:

```
 def back():
    global char_count # contains total char count
    text.delete(char_count)
```

I also tried to adjust the last line to text.delete(char_count-1) thinking that may be the index count was off by 1 (I wasn't sure if my count matched index in the Text widget). The above code doesn't delete anything.

2) I was also trying to see how a range of text can be deleted. I have checked online and I find to delete the entire Text content, people use:

```
   text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
```

This works, but if I try another approach to delete everything from the second index as follows, nothing happens:

```
   text.delete("2.0", tk.END)
```

I wanted to ask what is the right way to delete the last character or a range from the text, assuming the indices to be used are in variables and not hard coded like "2.0" above.

Answer (score 4):

1) The Text widget always insures that the last character in the widget is a newline character, so you could delete the one you want, the second-to-last character, like this:

```
def back():
    text.delete('%s - 2c' % 'end')
```

No need to keep track of the character count in the Text widget.

A full working sample is here:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    import tkinter as tk
else:
    import Tkinter as tk

def back():
    text.delete('%s - 2c' % tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Delete', command = back).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

2) Watch out for `text.delete("2.0", tk.END)`. *"2.0"* is the start of the second line. The **index** of a Text widget has different formats, but the simplest is text string 'X.Y', where X is the line number (starting at 1) and Y is the column number (starting at 0) of that line. And the columns don't always line up, since a tab character will take a single column but look much wider in the Text widget.

You can call the delete() method with variables, like `text.delete(startIndex, stopIndex)`. The trick is making sure that the indexes are valid. '1.0' represents the very first position in the Text widget, and 'end' represents the very last.  Have a look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm for a pretty reasonable and concise look at Text widgets and how their indexes work.

There are different ways to manipulate a Text index, but some of the most common are with the text.index(*arg*) method, which returns an 'X.Y' representation of *arg*, and 
the `nextpos = text.index('%s + 1 chars' % thispos)` format, which allows you to do basic math on an index. In this case, it would set **nextpos** to the next column.  But the '+ 1' can be plus or minus any_number, and the 'chars' can be 'lines' or 'words'. There's a lot to it. But have a look at that effbot.org page.